# SQLSTATE[HY000] error when creating a table?

Tags: mysql

This is my SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `customer_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `token` varchar(100),
  `created_at` datetime,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_PASSWORD_RECOVERY_CUSTOMER` FOREIGN KEY (`customer_id`) REFERENCES `customer_entity` (`entity_id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1
```

Its always giving me:  Can't create table 'mytable' (errno: 150) SQL.sql

Comment: That may be related to the constraint definition. Try to create your table without the constraint. If you can create the table, then check your constraint definition for issues.

Comment: Yes, that was the problem, but why? How else can I create the contraint?

Answer (score 0):

As posted in my comment to your question, the error you are getting has to do with the constraint definition. You should then check the [proper syntax for the constraint](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html).

I think the problem is that you are not indexing the `customer_id` column. Try to index it:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `customer_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `token` varchar(100),
  `created_at` datetime,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  INDEX cust_id(customer_id), -- ADD THIS
  FOREIGN KEY (`customer_id`) 
      REFERENCES `customer_entity` (`entity_id`) 
      ON UPDATE CASCADE 
      ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

(just as a precaution and dumb-check, verify that `customer_entity` is also an InnoDB table)